# How to keep input status when click back button?

Tags: javascript, html

Click reset button on page test1, the input of id become enabled. I edit the value and then click submit button, and it go to page test2. Now click back button it will return to page test1. THe problem is, the input keeps edited value but the status is disabled. I want it keep enable. How to solved this problem.
(It works on FireFox but does not work on IE and Chrome.)

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> test1 </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setEnable(){
        document.myForm.id.disabled = false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="myForm" action="test2.html">
    <input type=text name="id" value="test" disabled/>
    <input type=button value="reset" onclick=setEnable(); />
    <input type=submit />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title> test2 </title>
</head>
<body>
<input type=button value="back" onclick=history.back(); />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

1) is you can accomplish this with js and cookies...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

the idea is to create a cookie when the user leaves the page saving the form data, and then when the same page is loaded again, check if there is a cookie and if so then set the form fields to the cookie data....

it's pretty simple just look at a couple examples.

2) coordinate the form with a server using php or AJAX and have the page rendered with a context containing the data from the first submit and repopulating the form with the context data

Comment: Thank you, the first solution is perfect for me.